# Split string from digits/number according to sentence length

Tags: python, string, split

I have cases that I need to seperate chars/words from digits/numbers which are written consecutively, but I need to do this only when char/word length more than 3.

For example,
*input*

`ferrari03`

*output* must be:

`ferrari 03`

However, it shouldn't do any action for the followings:
`fe03`, `03fe`, `03ferrari` etc.

Can you help me on this one ? I'm trying to do this without coding any logic, but `re` lib in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.sub()` we can try:

```py
inp = ["ferrari03", "fe03", "03ferrari", "03fe"]
output = [re.sub(r'^([A-Za-z]{3,})([0-9]+)$', r'\1 \2', i) for i in inp]
print(output)  # ['ferrari 03', 'fe03', '03ferrari', '03fe']
```

Given an input word, the above regex will match should that word begin with 3 or more letters and end in 1 or more digits.  In that case, we capture the letters and numbers in the `\1` and `\2` capture groups, respectively.  We replace by inserting a separating space.